# Existence of independent random variables with normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

I was reading Amir Dembo's *Probability Theory* and there is a point that confuses me in the proof of Lindeberg's Central Limit Theorem for traingular arrays.  He seems to use a result:

(Under some condition) if $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ are multually independent random variables with finite mean $\{\mu_k\}$ and finite variance $\{\sigma_k^2\}$, then there exists random variables $Z_1,Z_2,...,Z_n$ with normal distributions $\{N(\mu_k,\sigma_k^2)\}$ on the same probability space such that $X_1,X_2,...,X_n,Z_1,Z_2,...,Z_n$ are mutually independent .$-------------(*)$

I think this statement, in general, is not true. But it may hold under some conditions. So I have a conjecture:

*Conjecture:* For a probability space $(\Omega,P)$, if the following condition is true: for every $n>0$ there exists random variables $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n$ that are mutually independent, then $(*)$ is correct.

Is this guess true? Or are there any other condition that makes $(*)$ correct?

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: I don't think the book is saying that $Z_i$'s exist on the same space.

Comment: Oh I mean that his statement is involved in the proof of the theorem, so it  depents on some condition in the theorem, but I don't know what condition he used.

Comment: The statement you marked as $(*)$ is unfalsifiable in its present form. As Kabo said, the $Z_i$ variables need not exist on the same probability space as the $X_i$ variables at all, so such variables trivially exist independent of everything else in the sentence, and the starred statement is certainly true in every case. So the issue is either that (a) you have truncated too much of the statement $(*)$ and need to write more of it, or (b) it's possible you're misunderstanding the statement itself, I suppose. But if your question is, "Must these $Z_i$ variables always exist?" the answer is yes.

Comment: I'm also not sure if you're trying to convey something by switching from $X_i$ in the original $(*)$ statement to $Y_i$ in your conjecture. And now that I've taken a second look at it, I can't tell what's different about your conjecture than the original statement. Perhaps the main point is that the variables ($X_i$ or $Y_i$) aren't important in the construction of the $Z_i$'s; only the $\mu_k$ and $\sigma_k$ terms are.

Comment: I'm so sorry that I had left something important and now I add it.: the random variables $X_1,X_2,...,X_n,Z_1,Z_2,...,Z_n$ are mutually independent.

Comment: You also added the phrase "on the same probability space" to $(*)$. I don't have a copy of the text, but I'd be surprised if that phrase was in there. CLT statements are statements about convergence in distribution, so the underlying probability space is rarely important. Is that condition actually in the original text? Moreover, even with the edits I still can't see the difference between $(*)$ and your conjecture, and $(*)$ would seem to be true in all cases (perhaps except the variables being defined on the same $\Omega$).

Comment: I think I get some point of you comments. At first I believed that he is saying the $\{Z_k\}$ are on the same probability, but now I think myself wrong. As you say, the underlying sapce is rarely important. Thank you for your help! Aaron and Kabo.